# Parsing Image URL Android

Tags: android, image, parsing, url

I have parsed several items of weather data from an online xml file. One of the nodes is a URL of an image I want to display. I have managed to parse it and save it as a String variable and it displays in the app as a String. How do I get it to display the image instead of text?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to download the image and store it in a Bitmap object.

Then, display it with an ImageView.

[This answer describes how you can do it in some detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471935/how-to-load-an-imageview-by-url-in-android/2472175#2472175).

Comment: I get a number of 'cannot be resolved' errors with this code despite adding all the recommended imports - am I missing something obvious or is the code out of date? Thanks

Comment: Use async task to download the image. Download it in doInBackground() and in postExecute() update ui accordingly. Makes it more efficient.

Comment: I'm new to Android development - are there any good tutorials you could recommend to do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   ProgressDialog pd;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1))
    .execute("Your URL");
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;
    DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
        }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
          pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
          pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    }



    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
    String urldisplay = urls[0];
    Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
    try {
    InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
    mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        pd.dismiss();
    bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
    }         
 }
```

Comment: This should work for download image. In your postExecute you can display the image.

Comment: url1 = new URL("ur url);
     url1.openConnection().setConnectTimeout(1000);
     your bitmap =BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url1.openConnection().getInputStream());

Comment: Thanks, will give this a go now :)